# 'function' object has no attribute 'today'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm getting this error while trying to use datetime functions. I'm using IDLE Python 3.7. datetime functions used to work but they don't now out of nowhere.

## Error:

```
    updatedate = datetime.date.today()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'today'
```

I've tried using "import from" code to initiate more specific imports but they don't help. I've also tried putting import datetime inside of def constructor(): to no avail.

## Example of my Code:

```
import datetime

dictionary = dict()

def constructor():
    updatedate = datetime.date.today()
    dictionary['Update_Date'] = updatedate
    print(dictionary)
```

## results in the following:

```
      updatedate = datetime.date.today()
 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'today'
```

I want the datetime.date.today() function to save todays date as variable "updatedate" and then enter that date as the value of the key ['Update_Date'] in dictionary "dictionary"

Comment: Show us the complete stack trace.

Comment: did you `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`. I suspect the latter

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `import datetime` and not `from datetime import datetime`? The *module* `datetime` has a class `datetime.date` that has a method called `today()`; whereas the class `datetime.datetime` has a method called `date()`.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me: https://repl.it/@codeguru/AngryDimgrayAstronomy

Comment: You probably overwrote your `datetime` reference with `datetime.datetime` at some point, resulting in `datetime.date` being the `date()` function inside `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: I'm guessing you assigned something to `datetime.date` and/or named a file `datetime.py`, but you haven't given us enough information to truly diagnose the problem.

Comment: code works for me too..make sure things were imported properly

Comment: How do I check whether datetime is importing properly? I know my code should be working. I can import "random" and "time" funcitons just great and practice with those, but when I import datetime, python shits a brick.

Comment: user2357112 was right. I had another python file called datetime which cause python to have an aneurysm. Thanks for the help dude!

Answer (score 0):

In `datetime` there is another object inside it called `datetime`. You must use this instead of `date`.

Example:

```py
import datetime

dictionary = dict()

def constructor():
    updatedate = datetime.datetime.today()
    dictionary['Update_Date'] = updatedate
    print(dictionary)
```

Comment: why downvote? This is *mostly* correct. The `datetime` module has a `datetime` object with a `date` method and the `datetime` module also has a `date` object.

Comment: @modesitt: No it's not. `datetime.datetime.today()` may be a thing that exists, but so is `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: I see - thought he kept it `datetime.date.today()`. `datetime.datetime.today()` seems to just return now.

Comment: @user2357112 @modesitt Is this not was asked in the question? I quote: `want the datetime.date.today() function to save todays date as variable "updatedate"`

Comment: datetime.datetime.today() would give me the exact date and time of when my code is run but it shouldn't affect whether or not it works. From my understanding that's the case, anyway.

Comment: I am saying you must replace `datetime.datetime.date.today` with `datetime.datetime.today` in order to achieve what you want. Is this not true?

Comment: @CalderWhite check the output of `datetime.datetime.today` vs `datetime.date.today`.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't use `datetime.datetime.date.today`, and even if it did, the correct replacement would be `datetime.date.today`, not `datetime.datetime.today`.

Comment: user2357112 was right. I had another python file called datetime which cause python to have an aneurysm.